# Change ganache Owner Account in WEB3J from account[0] to account[1]or account[2]

Tags: solidity, ganache, smart-contract-wallets, web3j, java

I'm looking for a way to change owner of the smart contracts in java web3j as we do in web3 javascript using `from`:

```
//using account for transaction in javascript
await contract.function(param1, param2, {from: account1, value: balance});
await contract.function(param1, param2, {from: account2, value: balance});
```

I can't find any solution regarding this for java web3j to change account for transaction.

```
contract.function(param1, param2).sendAsync();
```

It uses default account[0] for all the transactions. I want to change the owner for various transctions. How to write  `{from: account2, value: balance})` in java

Would be nice to get a suitable answer for web3j to change account, thanks.

Code I'm stucked with:

```
public class accessControl {
    Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("HTTP://127.0.0.1:9545"));
    private final static String PRIVATE_KEY = "*************************";
    private final static BigInteger GAS_LIMIT = valueOf(6721975L);
    private final static BigInteger GAS_PRICE = valueOf(20000000000L);
    String ownerID = web3j.ethAccounts().send().getAccounts().get(0);
    String manufacturerID =  web3j.ethAccounts().send().getAccounts().get(1);
    String wholesalerID = web3j.ethAccounts().send().getAccounts().get(2);
    String retailerID = web3j.ethAccounts().send().getAccounts().get(3);
    private final String CONTRACT_ADDRESS = deployContract(web3j, getCredentialsFromPrivateKey());
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new accessControl();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private accessControl() throws Exception {

        printWeb3Version(web3j);

        System.out.println("<-------------------ACCOUNTS----------------------->");
        System.out.println("CONTRACT ADDRESS: " + CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
        System.out.println("Contract Owner: " + ownerID);
        System.out.println("Manufacturer ID: " + manufacturerID);
        System.out.println("Wholesaler ID: " + wholesalerID);
        System.out.println("Retailer ID: " + retailerID);

        //System.out.println("DA: "+deployAddress);

        SupplyChain supplychain= loadContract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, web3j, getCredentialsFromPrivateKey());

        supplychain.addRetailer(retailerID).send();
        supplychain.addWholesaler(wholesalerID).send();
        supplychain.addManufacturer(manufacturerID).send();

        supplychain.produceItemByManufacturer(valueOf(1), "mullick", "milk", valueOf(1)).send();
        supplychain.packageItemByManufacturer(valueOf(1)).send();
        supplychain.sellItemByManufacturer(valueOf(1), valueOf(1)).send();
        supplychain.purchaseItemByWholesaler(valueOf(1), "mr. mullick", BigInteger.valueOf(1)).send();
        supplychain.shippedItemByManufacturer(valueOf(1)).send();
        supplychain.receivedItemByWholesaler(valueOf(1)).send();
        supplychain.sellItemByWholesaler(valueOf(1), BigInteger.valueOf(1)).send();
        supplychain.purchaseItemByRetailer(valueOf(1),"mrs. mullick", BigInteger.valueOf(1)).send();
        supplychain.shippedItemByWholesaler(valueOf(1)).send();
        supplychain.receivedItemByRetailer(valueOf(1)).send();
        supplychain.fetchItemBufferOne(valueOf(1)).send();
        supplychain.fetchItemBufferTwo(valueOf(1)).send();
        supplychain.fetchWholesaler(valueOf(1)).send();
        supplychain.fetchRetailer(valueOf(1)).send();
        supplychain.fetchitemHistory(valueOf(1)).send();

    }

    private void printWeb3Version(Web3j web3j) {
        Web3ClientVersion web3ClientVersion = null;
        try {
            web3ClientVersion = web3j.web3ClientVersion().send();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assert web3ClientVersion != null;
        String web3ClientVersionString = web3ClientVersion.getWeb3ClientVersion();
        System.out.println("Web3j client version: " + web3ClientVersionString);
    }

    private Credentials getCredentialsFromPrivateKey() {
        return Credentials.create(PRIVATE_KEY);
    }

    private String deployContract(Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials) throws Exception {
        return SupplyChain.deploy(web3j, credentials, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT).send().getContractAddress();
    }

    private SupplyChain loadContract(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials) throws Exception {
        return SupplyChain.load(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, web3j, credentials, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT);
    }

}
```

I need to change the IDs when the owner changing from manufacturer (account[1])-> wholesaler(account[2]) -> retailer (account[3]), with respective to their ID so the payment get deducted from their account, not from the account[0] everytime

---

Changes I made as you showed,

```
private final static String account0_privatekey = "0**********";
private final static String account1_privatekey = "1**********";
private final static String account2_privatekey = "2**********";
private final static String account3_privatekey = "3**********";
//generate contract address
private final String CONTRACT_ADDRESS = deployContract(web3j, getCredentialsFromPrivateKey(account0_privatekey));
```

and,

```
    private accessControl() throws Exception {
....
        SupplyChain supply_chain_account0= loadContract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, web3j, getCredentialsFromPrivateKey(account1_privatekey));
        SupplyChain supply_chain_account1= loadContract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, web3j, getCredentialsFromPrivateKey(account1_privatekey));
        SupplyChain supply_chain_account2= loadContract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, web3j, getCredentialsFromPrivateKey(account2_privatekey));
        SupplyChain supply_chain_account3= loadContract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, web3j, getCredentialsFromPrivateKey(account3_privatekey));

        supply_chain_account0.addRetailer(retailerID).send();
        supply_chain_account0.addWholesaler(wholesalerID).send();
        supply_chain_account0.addManufacturer(manufacturerID).send();

        supply_chain_account1.produceItemByManufacturer(valueOf(1), "mullick", "milk", valueOf(1)).send();
        supply_chain_account1.packageItemByManufacturer(valueOf(1)).send();
        supply_chain_account1.sellItemByManufacturer(valueOf(1), valueOf(1)).send();
        supply_chain_account2.purchaseItemByWholesaler(valueOf(1), "mr. mullick", valueOf(1)).send();
        supply_chain_account1.shippedItemByManufacturer(valueOf(1)).send();
        supply_chain_account2.receivedItemByWholesaler(valueOf(1)).send();
        supply_chain_account2.sellItemByWholesaler(valueOf(1), valueOf(1)).send();
        supply_chain_account3.purchaseItemByRetailer(valueOf(1),"mrs. mullick", valueOf(1)).send();
        supply_chain_account2.shippedItemByWholesaler(valueOf(1)).send();
        supply_chain_account3.receivedItemByRetailer(valueOf(1)).send();
....
}
```

Now it doesn't run at all and throws errors. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Can you pleases replace your question to be written in web3j code with a specific example?

Comment: Hello, my main question isn´t related to any specific code. Its just about how to change owner of the transaction in web3j as we do in web3js by passing ` {from: account2, value: balance}`

Comment: As I know when you create a transaction in webj you pass credentials. The code you published will connect to metamask and use the credentials there, so it wouldn't be possible in web3j

Comment: Yaa I understood, i got connected to ganache using web3j, and I'm working on supply chain project demo. And the project is working fine also. the payment is being made for the all stages from account[0], I need to change the account in each stage.

assume, manufacture = account[0], wholesaler = account[1], retailer =  account[2]. So when wholesaler pays to retailer it should be from account[1], not account[0]. It can be done in javascript using `{from:}`, but I can't find anything in java

Comment: As I said, you can't just perform transaction as anyone because than it wouldn't be secured right? So, in JS metamask prompts a window and you can sign the transaction with the account. In web3j you should pass the credentials of the account you need.

Comment: Its just a demo. I provided the code above, maybe it'll now help you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
getCredentialsFromPrivateKey()
```

In load contract, change the private key to the one owned by the account. you can create one contract per account you want.

**EDIT:**

```
private Credentials getCredentialsFromPrivateKey(String private_key) {
        return Credentials.create(private_key);
}
```

Than

```
private accessControl() throws Exception {
    ...
    SupplyChain supply_chain_account0= loadContract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, web3j, getCredentialsFromPrivateKey(account0_privatekey));
    SupplyChain supply_chain_account1= loadContract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, web3j, getCredentialsFromPrivateKey(account1_privatekey));
    SupplyChain supply_chain_account2= loadContract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, web3j, getCredentialsFromPrivateKey(account2_privatekey));
    ...
}
```

Comment: so if I change and  create contract for each transaction then how will I save the transaction which will lead to the next steps and next transactions?? Do you have any solution to it?? I checked about proxy contract regarding this but even that will create a lot of obstacles.

Comment: To use Proxy Contracts, I researched about it and got to know that upgrades to the OpenZeppelin truffle When using the OpenZeppelin Upgrades plugins, smart contracts may be upgraded to make changes to the code while keeping their address, state, and balance intact. By doing so, we may incrementally add new features to your project or address any faults you might see in production.

Comment: But after deploying with one account the problem still persist with web3j for changing the owner address during implementation. So seems we have to write supplychain.sol file for each participant in supply chain individually, considering them as different versions at each level which doesn't seem right. And as deploy-script and upgrade-scripts are written in javascript everywhere, can't find anything related to java related proxy contracts. This makes me again clueless with this problem.

Comment: You don’t create something new for each transaction. You only access the same contract from different accounts by passing loadContract other credentials than the one saved in PRIVATE_KEY which I guess it’s the key to account0

Comment: Yaa, got you. But can you show me a bit of implementation?

Comment: @MustakimMullick Look what I wrote, mark it as an answer if it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, @matank001. I made certain changes that you asked. But it didn't work. I hope I made the correct changes, I posted my answer too.